# Pictures folder disappeared in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

Pictures folder disappeared after installing gnome-tweaks in Ubuntu 19.04
1. I checked configs: cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs  the Pictures location is XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/" and I change it to XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures".
2. Restart Ubuntu
3. Checked config again and it is the same: XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
Then I did all 3 steps again but after removing gnome-tweaks and it is the same.
Can anybody help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mv .config/user-dirs.dirs .config/user-dirs.dirs.bak
```

then take a look in `cat .config/user-dirs.locale` that the right locale is set.

You can create a new .config/user-dirs.dirs with `xdg-user-dirs-update`

Comment: Thanks!!! Problem is solved.