# Lost Desktop folder in my Home folder

Tags: 20.04, display

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop that that takes 3 hard disks that I can plug in and remove at will. Obviously I can't remove the booted drive and I have to unmount the others before removal. I have a working disk and 3 rescue disks. Yesterday I reinstalled Ubuntu on one of the rescue disks and installed extra programs.
Today I found that the Desktop folder on my working disk was missing and the actual desktop displays the contents of my Home folder.
I've recreated the Desktop folder to no effect, except to be added to the desktop.
I've searched on Google and found no solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pictures folder disappeared in Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163706/pictures-folder-disappeared-in-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: I had a look and think that my locale is correct

Answer (score 1):

I've also lost my Desktop folder and everything in Home displays on the desktop.  Does it have anything to do with this entry in my user-dirs.dirs ?
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
In the file .config/user-dirs.dirs I changed `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"` to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"` (`XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Área de Trabalho"` in Portuguese), closed and opened the session again an it worked, the desktop window showed the content of Desktop folder instead of home folder again.